# How to remove " character within the double quotes on ubuntu?

Tags: regex, file, ubuntu, awk, quotes

I have a file with the condition like this :

```
"one","two","three"" four","five"
```

So I want to remove the quotes mark within the double quotes, so the output be like this :

```
"one","two","three four ","five"
```

How can I do that with awk function and regular expression on ubuntu? Thanks...

Comment: Asking a single question which covers the range of modifications to your input file that you need might get you a better answer then trying to break up the modifications into tiny individual pieces.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply look for `""` and replace it by an empty string.

Like:

```
sed -i 's/""//' *.txt
```

For example:

```
echo '"one","two","three"" four","five"' | sed 's/""//'
"one","two","three four","five"
```

Answer (score 1):

sed is the right tool for this.

```
$ echo '"one","two","three"" four","five"' | sed 's/\([^,]\)"\+\([^,]\)/\1\2/g'
"one","two","three four","five"
```

The above regex captures the character (*character not of a comma*) which exits before and after to one or more double quotes. So this would match the double quotes which exists at the center.

OR

```
$ echo '"one","two","three"" four","five"' | sed -r 's/([^,])"+([^,])/\1\2/g'
"one","two","three four","five"
```

- `[^,]` matches any character but not of a comma.
- `([^,])` matched character was captured into group 1. It's like aa temporary storage area.
- `"+` one or more `+`
- `([^,])` captures the following character which won't be a comma.
- `\1\2` all the matched chars are replaced with the characters stored inside  group index 1 and the group index 2.

**Update:**

```
$ echo '"one","two","three" vg " "gfh" four","five"' | sed -r 's/([^,])"+([^,])/\1\2/g;s/([^,])"+([^,])/\1\2/g'
"one","two","three vg  gfh four","five"
```

Comment: thanks mr Avinash for your help, but I want to ask, cause I can't totally undestand hahahaha. If I'm not wrong that's substitute to \1\2 what it means? And I'm still confused with the pattern \([^,]\)"\+\([^,]\) what that means, is + character means minimal one is occur? Thanks a lot

Comment: but when my string like this it can't be done :

"one","two","three" vg " "gfh"  four","five"

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
s="one","two","three"" four","five"'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/""/, "", $i)} 1' <<< "$s"
"one","two","three four","five"
```